# Designing a sortable Excel like list for Metro?

Tags: listview, sorting, windows-8

I know this is not the designing Q&A, but I figured I give it a try anyway. 
What's the recommended way to implement a list not unlike in Excel that you can sort and filter in a Windwos 8 Store (Metro) App?

Most examples that I can find use tiles, but I really don't think that is a very good solution for my situation. I just need to display links and their Social Media counts.

Here is a screenshot of the app:
http://apptivate.ms/apps/1276/super-social-media-tracker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows 8 apps the recommended way to solve your problem is tiles (ex. take a look at the Bing app). You can fit whatever information you need on a tile, so you can fit the link and your Social Media count on it. 
The users of Windows 8 are (will be) used to work with tiles, so there should be no problem with the user experience.

Answer (score 2):

Attached a proposal on how to structure the view. Hope that helps.[image: start page]
[image: detail view]